# Angular material Layout Directives not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-material

I am trying to use the Child-Alignment feature of Angular Material. 
Mentioned Here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

This does not seem to work. I have tried importing 

`import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';`
I also tried installing 
`import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';`

None of them is working.

Comment: Looks like you're going through the documentation of AngualJS's(1.x) Material but the the syntax you're specifying is for Angular's(2+) Material. Where exactly are you trying to use this in?

Comment: True. Just checked.  I am trying to use in angular 6. How to align in angular 2+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SiddAjmera commented you are using an AngularJS directive in Angular 6. I couldn't find anything similar from Angular 2+.

If you're trying to align components in your view I really recommend you look into the `display: flex` css property. Here's a [good explanation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on how to use it.